# Is there something like boost::asio for .NET (Mono)?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I need the functionality of boost::asio::io_service in a .NET (C#) program. Is there a library (Microsoft or 3rd-party) that has a similar functionality?

What I need is a class/mechanism like boost::asio::io_service that lets me asynchronously invoke handlers. With io_service I can "post" handlers from outside the thread in which the handlers are actually executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with boost:asio, but you get asynchronous I/O in .NET via the BeginXXX/EndXXX pattern. For example, see [Stream.BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread.aspx) and [Stream.EndRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.endread.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! This looks very promising. There is a AsyncMethodCaller. Now I just have to find a way to make sure that there is only one thread in which the handlers are executed.